# Extract Data from a Web Page - using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, data-extraction

Using VBA, I need to extract data from webpage http://emops.tse.com.tw/t21/sii/t21sc03_2011_9_e.htm

I am able to fetch all the data using following code:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://emops.tse.com.tw/t21/sii/t21sc03_2012_2_e.htm", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "67083361_zpid"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

But the problem is I don't want data from whole page. **I want data from the table where Industry name is Electron (It is the last table in this case)**

Any trick for the same please?

Comment: See if this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798260/html-parsing-of-cricinfo-scorecards/8846791#8846791

Comment: You might want to mark some of your questions solved, your questions appear to be answered, but you haven't acknowledged them - people are disinclined to help if you don't acknowledge solutions

Comment: They decided to do it all as *one* table for some reason, simplest to fetch the lot and, find "Industry: Electron" in A:A and delete everything above it

Comment: @AlexK. I have done it in the same way now :)

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
.WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage to .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
```

Add:

```
.WebTables = "2" below .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
```

'You will have to use trial and error with the "2" to find the exact table you are wanting to grab